# In synthesizable verilog, can we use assign statement in generate block?

Tags: verilog

For example, I have the below piece of code. Can we assign wire inside the generate block in synthesizable verilog? Can we use assign statement inside the generate block in synthesizable verilog?

```
genvar i;
generate
        for (i = 0; i < W; i=i+1) begin:m
                wire [2:0] L;
                assign L[1:0] = { a[i], b[i] };
        end
endgenerate
```

Comment: In future questions please show the error you are getting.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  It is possible.  A generate statement is just a code generator directive to the synthesizer.  Basically, it is just loop unrolling.  This is if the loop can be statically elaborated.  That is, the number of times the loop is to executed should be determinable at compile time.

```
genvar i;        
generate        
for (i = 0; i < 2 ; i++) {        
  assign x[i] = i;}        
endgenerate 

unrolls into         
assign x[0] = 0;        
assign x[1] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In synthesizeable Verilog, it is possible to use an assign statement inside of a generate block. All a generate block does is mimic multiple instants. Be careful though, because just like a for loop, it could be very big space-wise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use assign in generate statment, it is quite common to help parameterise the hook up modules

The original code has some issues: `L` is defined multiple times and it is only assigned 2 out of 3 bits

```
genvar i;
generate
  for (i = 0; i < W; i=i+1) begin:m
    wire [2:0] L;
    assign L[1:0] = { a[i], b[i] };
  end
endgenerate
```

Could be changed to:

```
localparam   W = 4;
reg  [W-1:0] a;
reg  [W-1:0] b;
wire   [1:0] L [0:W-1];

genvar i;
generate
  for (i = 0; i < W; i=i+1) begin:m
    assign L[i] = { a[i], b[i] };
  end
endgenerate
```

Here `L[i]` selects the i'th `wire [1:0]` part of L. While `a[i]` and `b[i]` are bit selects.